# jquery change colorbox pop up size with the change of screen size

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have two html div where the first one is the wrapper of the second one , i have been showing the content of two divs with the colorbox popup . I want to change the size of the content and  colorbox(if needed) when the screen size will be changed . Please help me . Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This will resize the colorbox (relative to the screen) when the window dimensions change:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $.colorbox.resize({
        width:"75%", //or whatever dimensions you want
        height:"75%"
    });
});
```